# Gather all PFRelation under the same PFQuery

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using `Parse` as my backend and I'm currently looking for a better way for my situation.
I'll use `Objective-C` in order to demonstrate but I didn't tag it as `Objective-C` because it's not language related.
**My situation is as follows:** I have a class let's call it X. that has a key let's call it Y which is PFRelation of type Z (`Y<Z>`).
I need to get a list of Z. like to query for Z (Z is all I'm interested in).
Moreover, if possible, I want to be able to limit the output of Z like PFQuery does.
**To sum up:** I need a `PFQuery` that will be able to do all the abilities of `PFQuery` e.g. `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` and `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` that the object I will be operating in, in the block will be of `NSArray` of type Z.

**My current solution:** I thought of querying for X where exists Y (so I won't get empty objects of X. and just for every X, load all Y's and go through all arrays of Z.

I really don't think my solution is the best, hoping for someone that can point me at another solution to fit my situation.

Comment: I'm having problems grasping what it is you're after. Could you try explaining with a more mundane example objects (like cars, parts, books, authors, albums, artists etc) instead of XYZ? Maybe it's just too early in the morning for me, but... oh well :-)

Comment: Let's say X is a car workshop and Y is a PFRelation of cars and Z is the type Car. I need a query to go through so I'll have only cars that match my query on the workshops. I think this should do... Once again early in the morning. Say if it's not good enough

Comment: Sooo, you want a list of cars, but only cars that... what? Only cars from a specific list of workshops? If the workshop meets a criteria, give me the cars they have? Can you provide some code you are already trying, or maybe some pseudo code? Or just provide the exact use case :-)

Comment: I want the list of cars that doesn't have any criteria. Its parent class, workshops meet a criteria. Like all cars that their workshop is in the usa. I don't have a psuedo... Because I'm seriously out of luck with how to make it efficient

Comment: If you still don't understand, please tell me , I'll update my question

Comment: I think we are on track now. You query for workshops using some criteria, and from the resulting list of workshops you want to retrieve all their cars, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but after the criteria like you said, I don't care about the workshops. I care only for the cars

Comment: I edited the question to add that `Y` is a PFRelation. seems like I forgot to mention it. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think might be what you are looking for:

```
PFQuery *wsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Workshop"];
[wsQuery whereKey:@"country" equalTo:@"USA"];  // or whatever your criterias
NSArray *workshops = [wsQuery findObjects];

for (PFObject *workshop in workshops) {
    PFQuery *carsQuery = [workshop relationforKey:@"cars"].query;
    [carsQuery setLimit:5];
    // Add whatever constraints you want here
    NSArray *wsCars = [carsQuery findObjects];
    for (PFObject *car in wsCars) {
        NSLog(@"Car make: %@", [car objectForKey:@"make"]);
    }
}
```

This will first get a list of all workshops, and then for each workshop will get a list of all the cars belonging to that workshop, and print the make (brand) for each car.

*UPDATE*

New suggestion based on comments:

```
PFQuery *wsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Workshop"];
[wsQuery whereKey:@"country" equalTo:@"USA"];

PFQuery *carQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Car"];
[carQuery whereKey:@"workshop" matchesQuery:wsQuery];
[carQuery setLimit:5];
[carQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *cars, NSError *error) {
    // cars contains only cars with workshops located in USA 
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is the answer I said I've got, it's lacking some capabilities. Like limit. e.g. if I want only 5 cars that their workshop is in the USA. P.S. is this the most efficient way possible?

Comment: That their workshops are in the USA is part of the workshop query. But notice that the relation-query is still a query, so you can add constraints to that one as well. If you provide the exact scenario you are after, I can try editing the query to match your use case.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a constraint in the carsQuery

Comment: that will give me 5 of each workshop. I need 5 at total. just set a count?

Comment: You want 5 cars total across all workshops, even though there might be 20? How would you determine which 5 to return?

Comment: That is why I said I want PFQuery capabilities. Even if there are 100. I'd like to be able to limit to 5. Not based on anything. I need the ability

Comment: Ok, so why not skip the workshops and query directly for cars? Give me 5 cars that belong to a workshop in usa (you would need an inner query for the workshops here). I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Was my last suggestion what you needed, @user2558461?

Comment: I don't understand how did you reach workshops via Car

Comment: How is Car related to Workshop since you cannot reach ws through car? A workshop can have many cars, but a car can only be sold (or whatever) by 1 workshop (at a time, at least). How are they related?

Comment: a workshop has a PFRelation for Car, so via Workshop you can list all cars, but via car you got nothing